# Should you downvote an answer that didn't work for you, even if it worked for others?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting, down-votes

Is it justified to downvote an answer that didn't work for you specifically, even if it worked for others?

Comment: You can vote however you see fit. If there is an issue with an answer from your POV, down vote now,  not later, vote often. Your vote matters, not how others voted.

Comment: @bobble This looks like it could be for the whole network, IMHO.

Comment: How would you know whether or not it worked for others?

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure your vote is an educated one.

Comment: For answers, it simply states "This answer is not useful"

Answer (score 10):

You can vote however you want, really. Well, with [one notable exception](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/622284), anyway.

The voting tooltips across the network indicate "This answer is useful" and "This answer is not useful" for upvotes and downvotes respectively. If you find that an answer is not useful, regardless of its current score or the perceived notion that it was *previously* useful, then you are well within your right to vote accordingly. In fact, you *should* vote accordingly, because [voting is important](/help/why-vote).

Comment: And that this has to be explained, is the reason why downvotes aren't ideal solution for many problem that answers can face. Edits are the superior tool to make sure that an answer continue to be useful.

Answer (score 5):

You are free to vote as you see fit.

However, there are some additional considerations besides whether answer is being useful to you.

Purpose of voting is rating content. Good content is upvoted, poor content is downvoted. That makes it easier to find good answers to a problem. Experts in the question topic will often upvote good answers and downvote poor ones to make it easier for non experts choosing proper solution.

However, some problems can have different solutions and not all solutions apply to every scenario. Downvoting otherwise good answer, just because it is not useful for you skews the rating. It may send wrong signal to others where such answer would be a proper one.

There is also a problem with aging answers that were valid at some point in time. Just because they no longer apply in new scenarios that does not mean that nobody in the future will benefit from those answers.

If the answer is otherwise good, but it is not clear that it applies to specific scenario then better option than downvoting is editing an answer to make it clear under which conditions it works or under which conditions it does not work, or you can just leave the comment under answer.

Bottom line is that you should focus on quality, when downvoting posts, not just their usefulness for your particular situation. If the answer is completely wrong in all situations, offers poor advice, is otherwise low quality or has other issues besides not being useful to you then downvoting is appropriate.

If you are not sure how to rate some post (question or answer), then just don't vote on it.

Comment: This is the approach im taking now but sometimes I get annoyed when a answer has alot of upvotes and doesn't work in my case.

Comment: I can understand the frustration. I have been in similar situations. But don't vote with your heart, vote with your head.

Comment: Downvoting answers to the question you are searching for and do not answer it accurately is the correct behavior @bakalolo. If the question asked is the same you are having, downvoting the answer as if was you that asked it is totally expected.

Comment: @Braiam You haven't read my answer carefully. Downvoting is appropriate only if the answer is completely wrong. Many questions, especially canonicals, contain different answers that work or don't work under specific conditions while core question (problem) is the same. Downvoting such answers where they don't work because they cover slightly different scenario or older version of the technology, but are otherwise correct and good answers is WRONG (yes, you are still free to downvote if you like, but that does not mean it is the best thing to do).

Comment: Here is what I read of your answer and I thoroughly reject. "Downvoting otherwise good answer, just because it is not useful for you skews the rating". Vote is designed to tell if an answer is useful to me and solely to me. Not to others but to me, and that is what everyone should live by. Telling people that they should gaslight themselves into not seeing how an answer is useful, sowing self-doubt is something that only abusive relationships promote. I despise that, and you telling other users to do that and convince me that I didn't understand that, are hall marks of such relationship.

Comment: @Braiam Voting is not just for you but it is also a hint to others. How is taking into consideration that some answer offers __good and correct__ solution to others abuse? How is arguing that considering broader picture in place that thrives on collaboration instead of your own self serving interest abuse? You are coming to some really weird conclusions.

Answer (score 2):

*Personally*, rather than seeing it as plus or minus one - I'd suggest not voting at all on *quality* posts that didn't work for you (and if its clear why comment *what happened* - not "this didn't work") so others may benefit.

If there was an *obvious* issue - I'd downvote and comment, and for low effort posts just a downvote

If its useful, of course, the full range of positive reinforcement. upvotes, bounties and accepts

On the whole I think there's 2 goals here. Finding the answers *you* need, and building a knowledge base, and voting should take both into account.

Comment: "quality posts that didn't work for you" how a quality post doesn't work for the question asked?

Comment: Well - if its detailed, specific, and... didn't work for your specific case, it might work for someone else. Hence the suggestion of commenting on what went wrong.

Comment: Well, if it didn't work for my specific case and my case is the one detailed on the question, it didn't work for the specific case of the question and therefore a wrong answer.

Answer (score -1):

You are free to use the votes however you like. In fact, you should vote however you like in spite of however everyone voted. You are evaluating the post usefulness **to you**, not to others. If a post is not useful **to you** when it should be (because the question accurately describe your scenario), then downvoting it is the expected course of action. You should never take into account the votes on others on the post. That's why I downvote post that I can't edit and are obsolete or misleading.

Comment: I fully agree that people should not vote on posts purely based on how others have voted. But I cannot agree with that _not being useful to you_ is the only consideration people should make when deciding how to vote. What is obsolete to you is not necessarily obsolete to others.

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile it's my vote and I vote on whenever or not an answer is useful to me. If I fail to see how an answer is useful to me, I downvote and comment asking for clarification, but the downvote will always be there. Once the author edit their post, I can reevaluate if the post is useful or not.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you should.

A vote is always personal. There is no such thing as an objective vote.
The worst you can do while voting is, making your vote depend on the votes of others.
There is no two ways about that.
Your vote is your vote for your reasons. If not, it is not your vote.

It really is that simple.